# mysql won't run in terminal, even inside correct directory?

Tags: mysql, terminal

I am trying to run mysql 5.7 on mac os x Sierra, but even when I'm in the correct directory the program won't run.  Here is the terminal:

```
➜  mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64 cd bin
➜  bin ls
innochecksum               mysqlbinlog
lz4_decompress             mysqlcheck
my_print_defaults          mysqld
myisam_ftdump              mysqld-debug
myisamchk                  mysqld_multi
myisamlog                  mysqld_safe
myisampack                 mysqldump
mysql                      mysqldumpslow
mysql_client_test_embedded mysqlimport
mysql_config               mysqlpump
mysql_config_editor        mysqlshow
mysql_embedded             mysqlslap
mysql_install_db           mysqltest_embedded
mysql_plugin               mysqlxtest
mysql_secure_installation  perror
mysql_ssl_rsa_setup        replace
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql        resolve_stack_dump
mysql_upgrade              resolveip
mysqladmin                 zlib_decompress
➜  bin mysql
zsh: command not found: mysql
➜  bin
```

What am I missing?  I have also tried:

```
➜  bin ./msql
zsh: no such file or directory: ./msql
➜  bin sh mysql
mysql: mysql: cannot execute binary file
➜  bin
```

Comment: Is ./msql a typo, or is that really what you tried? i.e. did you try ./mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to run a program from current directory you should use `./`:

```
./mysql
```

You can also add it to the PATH, then you are able to execute it from any directory with:

```
mysql
```

Comment: Neither seem to work:
➜  bin ./msql

zsh: no such file or directory: ./msql

➜  bin sh mysql

mysql: mysql: cannot execute binary file

➜  bin

Comment: typo? ./msql instead of ./mysql

Comment: I had the same problem, tried to solve that for almost 2 hours even I'm a quite experienced programmer. Even so, I just forgot that it is required for MySQL executable files :). Thanks maszter.